# Write binary in FORTRAN without extra information

Tags: numpy, fortran, fortran90

I have written a simple subroutine, which is supposed to write:

1. 1 byte = x93 (decimal 147)
2. 5 bytes = ASCII STRING(NUMPY)

https://pastebin.com/tbh3c57g

```
Subroutine  write_int32_vec(filename, vec)
    Implicit None
    character(len=1000), intent(in)     :: filename
    integer(4), intent(in)              :: vec(:)

    open(unit=p_un, file=filename, form="unformatted", status="replace")
    write (p_un) magic_num
    write (p_un) magic_str
    close(unit=p_un)
End Subroutine write_int32_ve
```

If I look at it in a hex Editor I get the following:

```
01 00 00 00 93 01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 4E 55 4D 50 59 05 00 00 00
```

which is in ASCII

```
�NUMPY
```

It seems Fortran writes before and after every write command the length of it in a 4-byte integer. How can I turn this off?

Answer (score -1):

It turns out

```
open(unit=p_un, file=filename, form="BINARY")
```

does the trick. Sadly this seems to be only available to ifort, but not gfortran.

Comment: Use `access="stream"`. Many questions and answers available here.